# Can a process wait for a PID that is not one of the children?

Tags: c, concurrency, posix, child-process, waitpid

I was wondering if we can use the system call

> waitpid()

to wait a pid of a grandchildren

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`waitpid()` is POSIX.

[The POSIX standard says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html):

> The *wait()* and *waitpid()* functions shall obtain status information (see Status Information) pertaining to one of the caller's child processes.

So the answer to your question is "No", at least from the standard's perspective.

---

This does not necessarily have to keep implementations from providing extensions to the standard.

From POSIX as well:

> Nothing in this volume of POSIX.1-2008 prevents an implementation from providing extensions that permit a process to get status from a grandchild or any other process, but a process that does not use such extensions must be guaranteed to see status from only its direct children.